# Detecting Slow Network in iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Is there any way to detect slow network in iOS without using private API's and core telephony framework (Since Apple may reject this while during review). The scenario is, I have to load a low quality image during slow network and a high quality image during good coverage. Is there any framework other than core telephony is available to manually calculate internet speed test. I searched a lot and still not getting any proper solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer following library - https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit